How to close window programmatically in SwiftUI in visionOS?
This is how I define many of my windows in Vision Pro app:
struct MyData: Codable, Hashable {
    var intValue: Int
    var stringValue: String
}

struct i2ElevatorApp: App {
    private var portraitSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 600)
    private var landscapeSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 400)
    private var landscapeSize2x : CGSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
    let sharedState = SharedState()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(sharedState)
        }.defaultSize(portraitSize)
        WindowGroup(id: "SubTransformationView", for: MyData.self) { data in
            if let data = data.wrappedValue {
                CardView(cardIndex: data.intValue, cardType: data.stringValue)
                    .environmentObject(sharedState)
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }.defaultSize(portraitSize)
    }
}

In a View usually there is an openWindow reference to be able to open a window
struct CardView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

And then this is how it is opened:
Button(action: {
    openWindow(id: "SubTransformationView", value: MyData(intValue: cardIndex, stringValue: cardType))
}) {
    Image(systemName: "lanyardcard")
}.clipShape(Circle())

But how cna I close a window programmatically?

It is important to see that I can have not only one, but many window opened, and not only a String identifies a window, but an other String and an Int, look MyData struct.

Use dismissWindow: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismisswindow
From the documentation above:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        Window("Auxiliary", id: "auxiliary") {
            AuxiliaryContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct DismissWindowButton: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissWindow) private var dismissWindow


    var body: some View {
        Button("Close Auxiliary Window") {
            dismissWindow(id: "auxiliary")
        }
    }
}


There are various dismiss options: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dismisswindowaction

You have not shown where you want to dismiss it from. Can you please reduce the code to a [mre] and specify from where you want to dismiss it?

Ahh sorry, I put here my question which referes only when id is SubTransfromationView but it has more parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78287838/how-to-call-dismisswindow-in-vision-pro-when-defined-with-a-struct

Why did you start a new question? And you still haven’t shown from where you want to dismiss it? Please edit this question with a [mre] (neither question has one) including from where you want to dismiss.

It is important to see that I can have not only one, but many window opened, and not only a String identifies a window, but an other String and an Int, look MyData struct.

That’s all fine. Please make a [mre]. For example, you have not included SharedState or CardView. And, you have not shown from where you want to dismiss the window.
